# How to control display of page lists on sidebar that doesn't have childrens

Tags: pages, child-pages

I am using the following code to list the child pages of current page on my sidebar. It is working very well.

```
$titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&depth=1&title_li=<div id="list-title-head">'.$titlenamer.'</div>' );
if (is_page( )) {
  $page = $post->ID;
  if ($post->post_parent) {
    $page = $post->post_parent;
  }
  $children=wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=' );
  if ($children) {
    $output = wp_list_pages ('echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=<div id="list-title-head">'.$titlenamer.'</div>');
  }
}
echo $output;
```

But If a parent menu has no childs, this code will list all the parent pages on my sidebar. How can I control this?

If the parent menu doesn't have any childs, then I wants to display certains pages I define. If this is not possible, I don't want to display anything for page that doesn't have childs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try replacing your `$children` definition, using [**`get_page_children()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) or [**`get_children()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children):

```
<?php
global $post;
$children = get_children( array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
) );
if ( $children ) {
    // Code to list child pages goes here
}
?>
```

Also, `wp_list_pages()` will always return a string (either populated or empty), so if you're going to test against it, use:

```
if ( '' != $children )
```

...instead of just:

```
if ( $children )
```

Because the latter will *always return true*, since the return is an (empty) string.